# How to turn a list of numpy array into a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have 900 lists of NumPy arrays. The format of lists is described as follows:

```
list(np.array()) or [np.array()]
```

I am trying to create a *NumPy array* of all these lists stacked eg.

```
array([list([np.array()]), list([np.array()]), list([np.array()]), ..., list([np.array()]), list([np.array()]), list([np.array()])]
```

Note: At the end the final array should have shapeequal to 900, AND NOT equal to 900,4
Thank you

Comment: The desired output format you describe is more likely to cause problems than solve any. Seriously, we get a lot of questions here where the *problem* is that the array was in the form you say you want. Can you tell us why you want that?

Comment: @ediamant do you want to combine multiple numpy array into a single one?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yes, you are right. I have a dataset in the described format and other data which I should transform in order to apply global implementations of my algorithms.
Note that I should not transform the initial data.

Comment: @ChayanBansal I want to combine multiple lists that contain NumPy arrays into a single NumPy array

Comment: ``np.array`, `np.stack` and `np.concatenate` are the primary tools for combing arrays into one.  But the mix of input shapes can make this harder or impossible.